# MyEclipse: pin folders to project/package explorer

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I am developing a web application in eclipse, which has a very large folder structure. However, most of the work is done in 4-5 folders. Is there a way to pin those folders, so that they are easily accessible (like the favorites in windows file explorer). Alternatively (even better), is there a way to create a custom view so that only desired folders are visible??

Comment: Use **Build Path =>Use as Source Folder** option for the required folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Resource Tagger plugin](http://taggerplugin.sourceforge.net/) for this. Also look at [Resource decorator](http://codeandme.blogspot.in/2013/02/enhance-your-navigator-by-decorating.html) plugin and filter the resources.

Answer (score 0):

A custom view is possible by using filters. Pull down the menu (the downward pointing triangle) at the top of the package explorer and select Filters. You can add patterns for the folders you want to exclude from the view.

Comment: However, is there any way to do the opposite?? Show only some specific, manually selected folders, without retaining the folder hierarchy??

Comment: I don't know of a way to only show the folders you want, rather than filter out folders. However, note that the package explorer can show java packages in a hierarchical view (folders and sub-folders) or a flat view (a list of packages are shown under the source folders). This is in the menu pulldown for the explorer.