# custom colors specific type eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors, mustache

I am working with Eclipse (3.6.x) and I would like to custom the colors of some specific files:

The files are *.mustache and i would like to color specific words or things such as "{{something}}" in bold.

Is there a way to create a custom "colors and fonts" for unknown kind of files for Eclipse such as *.mustache and define the colors preferences for key words and also key characters which are "{{}}"?

The most important for me would be to have {{}} in bold.

Thanks for helping !!
PF

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/24863331/1391924

Comment: That's interesting but that's not what I'm searching. I would like to custom the color of the content of the files not the files themselves.